# Swap JavaFX scene when clicking a button

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I am trying to create a program to teach people about GNU/Linux and the command line, I have my main.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    Stage window;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args); 
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("login.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Learnix");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 500));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

And the controller to go with it.

```
package sample;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import java.io.IOException;

public class loginController {
    public Button loginBtn;
    public void loginBtnClick() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("You are logged in");
     }
}
```

I have tried things such as:

```
FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("lessons.fxml"));
```

But I can't figure out how to get it to swap scenes. I have seen many tutorials on YouTube and it Stack Overflow but many of them have all of the JavaFX on the `main.java` and not in separate files as I am using scenebuilder.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either call `Stage.setScene()` to change the whole scene or just substitute a root to the new one by `Scene.setRoot()`:

```
Parent newRoot = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("lessons.fxml"));
primaryStage.getScene().setRoot(newRoot);
```

Comment: Also note you can get the stage from any node, e.g. in the controller you can do `Stage primaryStage = (Stage) loginBtn.getScene().getWindow();`

Comment: Fantastic! This works, thank you both for the fast response and the help